# How to change image cropping frame?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I want to change image cropping frame for my android project. I have now *image1* but I need *image2* please help me.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/edmodo/cropper I think this is helpful for this question. I have solved my problem from this .

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Cropper](https://github.com/edmodo/cropper) image cropping tool .
It provides a way to set an image in XML and programmatically, and displays a **resizable crop window** on top of the image. Calling the method `getCroppedImage()` will then return the Bitmap marked by the crop window.

Comment: I have tried with this code but it is not exact fulfill my demand.  Thank you for your help....